how to join table if i want data null
i want to join table, and i have 2 table like
Table : Suhu
ID_ROOM | SUHU_MIN | SUHU_MAX
----------------------------------
   1        10           15
   1        12           20
   1        15           25
   1        20           22

Table : RH
ID_ROOM | RH_MIN | RH_MAX
----------------------------------
   1        11       19
   1        14       18
   

and I want output like this :
ID_ROOM | SUHU_MIN | SUHU_MAX   | RH_MIN  | RH_MAX
----------------------------------------------------
   1        10           15          11        19
   1        12           20          14        18
   1        15           25          NULL      NULL
   1        20           22          NULL      NULL

I have used left join, and the result is like this

SELECT S.suhu_min, S.suhu_max, R.rh_min, R.rh_max
FROM SUHU S LEFT JOIN RH R ON S.ID_ROOM = R.ID_ROOM;

ID_ROOM | SUHU_MIN | SUHU_MAX   | RH_MIN  | RH_MAX
----------------------------------------------------
   1        10           15          11        19
   1        12           20          14        18
   1        15           25          11        19
   1        20           22          14        18 


What's the logic behind? Why should those rows get NULL?

And what result should be created if different id_room values occur in one table or in both tables? Please explain the detailed logic for all possible cases.

Here is the SQL query that you can use
But there must be a logic that differs one row from others
I sorted the rows by _MIN columns per ID_Room and joined two tables accordingly
select
t1.ID_ROOM,
t1.SUHU_MIN,
t1.SUHU_MAX,
t2.RH_MIN,
t2.RH_MAX
from (
select 
ID_ROOM,
ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by ID_ROOM order by SUHU_MIN) as rn,
SUHU_MIN,
SUHU_MAX
from suhu
) t1
left join (
select
ID_ROOM,
ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by ID_ROOM order by RH_MIN) as rn,
RH_MIN,
RH_MAX
from rh
) t2 on t1.ID_ROOM = t2.ID_ROOM
and t1.rn = t2.rn


I assume you want to compare min_value and max_value
SELECT S.suhu_min, S.suhu_max, R.rh_min, R.rh_max 
FROM SUHU S 
LEFT JOIN RH R ON S.ID_ROOM = R.ID_ROOM AND S.suhu_min<R.rh_min AND S.suhu_max<R.rh_max


This will not produce the result shown in the question. Better let OP clarify their requirements rather than doing assumptions.
